# Density of a Two-Piece Normal (or Split Normal) Distribution

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, cran

Is there a density function for the two-piece Normal distribution:

[image]

on CRAN? Thought I would check before I code one. I have checked the distribution task view. It is not listed there. I have looked in a couple of likely packages, but to no avail.

Update: I have added `dsplitnorm`, `psplitnorm`, `qsplitnorm` and `rsplitnorm` functions to the [fanplot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fanplot/index.html) package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you choose to construct your own version of the distribution, you might be interested in **distr**. It (and the related packages **distrEx**, **distrSim**, **distrTEst**, **distrTeach** and **distrDoc**) have been written to provide a unified interface for constructing new distributions from existing ones. (I constructed this example with the help of the wonderful vignette that accompanies the **distrDoc** package and which can be gotten by typing `vignette("distr")`.)

This implements the [split normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_normal_distribution), which may not be exactly what you are after. Using the **distr** toolset, though, it shouldn't be too hard to adjust this to fit your exact needs.

```
library(distr)

## Construct the distribution object.
## Here, it's a split normal distribution with mode=0, and lower- and
## upper-half standard deviations of 1 and 2, respectively.
splitNorm <- UnivarMixingDistribution(Truncate(Norm(0,2), upper=0), 
                                      Truncate(Norm(0,1), lower=0), 
                                      mixCoeff=c(0.5, 0.5))
## Construct its density function ...
dsplitNorm <- d(splitNorm)
## ... and a function for sampling random variates from it
rsplitNorm <- r(splitNorm)

## Compare the density it returns to that from rnorm()
dsplitNorm(-1)
# [1] 0.1760327    
dnorm(-1, sd=2)
# [1] 0.1760327    

## Sample and plot a million random variates from the distribution
x <- rsplitNorm(1e6)         
hist(x, breaks=100, col="grey")

## Plot the distribution's continuous density
plot(splitNorm, to.draw.arg="d")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I think it is what I am looking for (or at least a parametrization of what I am looking for).

Comment: @gjabel -- A simpler approach, which I'd probably use if I just needed the density, is to do something like this: `ifelse(x < 0, dnorm(x, mean=0, sd=2), dnorm(x, mean=0, sd=1))` (again for a distribution with mode=0, lower half sd=2, and upper half sd=1).