# How do I generate mixture distribution in r?

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I need to generate a sample of mixed distribution where 2/3 of a sample is an exponential distribution with rate = 1 and 1/3 of a sample is a normal distribution with mean = 0 and sd = 1. I don't know how do I use `dexp` and `dnorm` functions at the same time.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480529/r-function-to-generate-a-mixture-distribution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R : function to generate a mixture distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480529/r-function-to-generate-a-mixture-distribution)

Comment: you could maybe also simply create each separately and combine them later?